# Moving/trickling updates in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` which contains the path, the parent path and the size of the directory. *But*, the catch here is that the directory size *does not* include the size of sub-dirs. This requires me to "sweep" across the `DataFrame` multiple time and update it. Another catch is that I need to start at the bottom and re-compute data as I move up.

The current `DataFrame` looks like:

```
Parent    Path    Size

/        /a         10
/        /b         20
/a       /a/x       1
/a       /a/y       2
/a       /a/z       3
/a/x     /a/x/a1    99
```

I'm trying to compute something along the lines of:

```
Parent    Path    Size

/        /a         115 (sum of size of /a, /a/x)
/        /b         20
/a       /a/x       100 (sum of size of /a/x and /a/x/a1)
/a       /a/y       2
/a       /a/z       3
/a/x     /a/x/a1    99
```

Basically, the updates start at the bottom (i.e. leave nodes/directory) and trickle to the top level directories. I'm stumped as to how to iterate the dataframe starting at the bottom and ensure that all consecutive updates always pick up the latest values? Any ideas appreciated, thanks.

Snippet to create the dataframe:

```
txt = '''/       /a         10
/        /b         20
/a       /a/x       1
/a       /a/y       2
/a       /a/z       3
/a/x     /a/x/a1    99'''
rows = [ line.split() for line in txt.split('\n') ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=rows, columns=['Parent', 'Path', 'Size'])
df['Size'] = df['Size'].astype(float)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below might work for you: identify the depth `level` of each row, iterate bottom up and add respective `Size` to `parent` as identified by `Path`.

```
df['level'] = df.Path.str.count('/')

for level in reversed(range(1, max(df.level) + 1)):
    data = df[df.level==level]
    for i, row in data.iterrows():
        parent = '/'.join(row.Path.split('/')[:-1])
        df.loc[df.Path == parent, 'Size'] += int(row.Size)

df

  Parent     Path  Size  level
0      /       /a   115      1
1      /       /b    20      1
2     /a     /a/x   100      2
3     /a     /a/y     2      2
4     /a     /a/z     3      2
5   /a/x  /a/x/a1    99      3
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept this comment but just wanted to point out that this approach doesn't really work for large datasets (millions of rows). For e.g. to process 2 million records, it takes around 12 hours!!